# WPF Listview group by sub class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that contains a subclass

```
public class CustomerDate
    {
        public string Date { set; get; }
        public Customerdetails _Customerdetails { set; get; }
        public CustomerDate()
        {
            _Customerdetails = new Customerdetails();
        }
    }

public class Customerdetails
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }   
    public Customerdetails() { }
}
```

I Have a list of CustomerDate Objects that I want to bind to a listview grouped by subClass(Customerdetails).
My problem is that I can show SubClass property in listview's Gridview ({Binding Customerdetails.Name}) but I cannot show SubClass details in GroupStyle section.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Customerdetails.Name}" />
```

Not working But

```
<GridViewColumn    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Customerdetails.Name}"
```

is working.

Any Idea?

```
List<CustomerDate> CustomerDateList = new List<CustomerDate>();
.
.
.                  

lv.ItemsSource = DBAccess.GetBadMonthlyPaymentCustomers();
                            CollectionView view =
(CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);

PropertyGroupDescription gd = new PropertyGroupDescription("Customerdetails");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(gd);



 <ListView  x:Name="lv">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView  x:Name="GridView" >            
                <GridViewColumn    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"   />                
                <GridViewColumn    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Customerdetails.Name}"   />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Customerdetails.Name}" />                                          
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                                    </Grid>                                    
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of a `GroupItem` is a `CollectionViewGroup` and not `Customerdetails`.

A group may contain several `Customerdetails`. You can bind to the `Name` property of any of them using the `Items` property of the `CollectionViewGroup`, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].Name}" />
```

Comment: Thank you with this syntax it's not working but with a converter it works.

Comment: @Mamad: What do you mean? This binds to the `Name` property of the first item in the group. If you want to convert the value, you may use a converter. But a converter won't get invoked unless the binding actually works.

Comment: I tried this but it not works, I dont know why, but with converter it works. I posted an answer

Comment: Because {Binding Items[0].Name} didn't work. after that I realized that Items[0] is an Object of Class CustomerDate then I Update my answer with your answer and my update for it.

Answer (score 0):

This two solutions work for me thank to @mm8 :

```
<local:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 

 public class NameConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
            return ((CustomerDate)((CollectionViewGroup)value).Items[0]).Customerdetails.Name;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
```

Items[0] is an Object of Class CustomerDate so its working this way too:

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Items[0].Customerdetails.Name}" />
```